# How to post message on Facebook Wall with offline access

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am trying to send message from my asp.net website running on localhost with offline access.
Can I post data on fb wall when my asp.net web-site is running on localhost is so then please provide me some solution.
I have tried using graph api provided by facebook on developers.facebook.com and I am sending code from sever-side.

Answer (score 1):

The permission named `Offline Access` has been [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/).

You can do so by [creating a facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/).

When configuring, your app's [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) should include the permission to post on behalf of your user (`publish_stream` should do).

Give the app permission for your user - visit `https://apps.facebook.com/{your_app_name_or_id}/`, you will be asked to allow the app certain permissions regarding your user. Allow.

Obtain the app's [token](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/).

Access the graph API using the token you received. One way (should make it easier, I hadn't a chance to go over it thoroughly myself) is using [CS SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/).